# How to modify existing highlight group in vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

If I have an existing highlight group in vim via link, for example

```
hi link my_highlight_group my_default_color
```

Is it possible to add 'bold' to my_highlight_group without changing my_default_color? Following does not work:

```
hi my_highlight_group gui=bold
```

Surprisingly, I can add bold if my_highlight group is defined directly (not via link):

```
hi my_highlight_group guifg=#F0000
hi my_highlight_group gui=bold
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As "too much php" has said, there is no direct way to say "create a value that looks like that one and add bold".  The best way is to modify your colour scheme.  If you're not using a custom colour scheme, copy one from the main vim installation directory to your ~/.vim/colors directory and edit it to suit you.  Alternatively, search on the vim scripts page and try some of the many that are available.

Shameless plug: if you want one that's easier to edit than the standard format, try my ["Bandit" colour scheme](http://sites.google.com/site/abudden/contents/Vim-Scripts/bandit-colour-scheme).

If you **really** want to be able to add bold on the fly, you'll need a fairly complex script, like the one below.  Note that this won't be saved for your next session unless you call it automatically *after* loading your colour scheme or by doing something like:

```
:autocmd ColorScheme AddBoldToGroup my_highlight_group
```

The script in all it's enormity is below.  As far as I am aware, there is no significantly quicker way of doing this!  Obviously you could save a few lines by writing less verbose code, but the general idea of using `redir` and `silent hi` repeatedly is the only way.

```
" Call this with something like
"
" :AddBoldToGroup perlRepeat
"
command! -complete=highlight -nargs=1 AddBoldToGroup call AddBoldToGroup(<f-args>)
function! AddBoldToGroup(group)
    " Redirect the output of the "hi" command into a variable
    " and find the highlighting
    redir => GroupDetails
    exe "silent hi " . a:group
    redir END

    " Resolve linked groups to find the root highlighting scheme
    while GroupDetails =~ "links to"
        let index = stridx(GroupDetails, "links to") + len("links to")
        let LinkedGroup =  strpart(GroupDetails, index + 1)
        redir => GroupDetails
        exe "silent hi " . LinkedGroup
        redir END
    endwhile

    " Extract the highlighting details (the bit after "xxx")
    let MatchGroups = matchlist(GroupDetails, '\<xxx\>\s\+\(.*\)')
    let ExistingHighlight = MatchGroups[1]

    " Check whether there's an existing gui= block
    let MatchGroups = matchlist(ExistingHighlight, '^\(.\{-}\) gui=\([^ ]\+\)\( .\{-}\)\?$')
    if MatchGroups != []
        " If there is, check whether "bold" is already in it
        let StartHighlight = MatchGroups[1]
        let GuiHighlight = MatchGroups[2]
        let EndHighlight = MatchGroups[3]
        if GuiHighlight =~ '.*bold.*'
            " Already done
            return
        endif
        " Add "bold" to the gui block
        let GuiHighlight .= ',bold'
        let NewHighlight = StartHighlight . GuiHighlight . EndHighlight
    else
        " If there's no GUI block, just add one with bold in it
        let NewHighlight = ExistingHighlight . " gui=bold"
    endif

    " Create the highlighting group
    exe "hi " . a:group . " " NewHighlight
endfunction
```

Comment: Shameless plug: If you don't want to copy entire colorschemes into your .vim folder, [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1641) allows you to put small customizations into .vim/after/colors. And Bravo for posting that code, I'd give you +4 if I could.

Comment: @too much php: That plugin looks good, thanks for the link (and for the Bravo!)

Comment: Add this code before this line: " Extract the highlighting details (the bit after "xxx")
(The nazi's ignored my edit for some alt-left reason, and they are wrong. You need this code or else the regex will not work as expected if verbose is on):

" Trim verbose-mode highlight output, see :help highlight-verbose
if &verbose
    let GroupDetails = substitute(GroupDetails, '\s\+\Last set from\_.*', '', 'g')
endif

Comment: Great work... so many years later still works.  Thank you.

Comment: @DrAl, two small bugs in the code: 1) StartHighlight group needs to include trailing space and be optional, or the pattern does not match when "gui" is the first entry on the lie - uncommon but possible. 2) GuiHighligh only contains value so need to add . "gui=" . to NewHighlight recombination.

Answer (score 3):

Years had passed and now the question has a much more straightforward solution: `hlget()` and `hlset()` functions.

It's still true that if you want to modify a color scheme, copying it first and modify the copied version would be a better solution.

An example of adding bold attribute to types' highlight:

```
" Get the highlight group, resolving links
let hl = hlget("Type", v:true)[0]
" Set GUI attributes
let hl.gui = hl->get("gui", {})->extend(#{ bold: v:true })
" Set the highlight group
call hlset([hl])
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing the attributes on a group which is linked to another will disconnect the link. AFAIK there is no easy way to copy the colors from `my_default_color` into `my_highlight_group`. You will just have to copy the color values by hand.

This shouldn't be a big issue though, you should have all your highlight groups defined in your colorscheme file, so just put those two next to each other:

```
hi my_default_color   guifg=#000088
hi my_highlight_group guifg=#000088 gui=bold
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want this for one syntax type, you should just make a new group name, my_bold_default_color, and apply the bold attribute to that.